# One expected line of output is not printed

Tags: java

```java
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Activity3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Variables
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random Machine = new Random();
        int num = Machine.nextInt(10);
    
        do {
            System.out.println("Guess the random generated number of the machine from 1-10");
            int guess = input.nextInt();
    
              
            if (guess == num) {                 
                 System.out.println("Correct number= " + num);
                 System.out.println("You Win!");                    
            } else if (guess <= 0 && guess >= 11) {                 
                 System.out.println("Invalid Number!");
            }

            if (guess > 1 && guess < 10){
                System.out.println("You Lose:<");                           
            }                                
               
            System.out.println("Do you want to try again?");
             
            
        } while (input.next().equalsIgnoreCase("YES"));
        input.close();

    } 
}
```

If I guess the correct number it outputs `" you win!"`.
If I guess wrong it outputs `"you lose"`. But If I guess a number that isn't in 1-10 it doesn't output the `"Invalid Number"` and just proceeds to output the `"Do you want to try again?"`.

Comment: Read the input as a single line of text (`Scanner#nextLine`), check for the exit condition, if it's not `YES`, parse the `String` value to `int` and compare it with the `num` value

Comment: check `guess <= 0 && guess >= 11` any one  number will NEVER be less than 1 **AND** greater than 10 (at the same time) || also note that `Machine.nextInt(10)` will generate numbers between 0 and 9 inclusive

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions need to be about something specific related to programming. Our goal is for questions to not only be helpful to the asker, but also anyone else with a similar issue in the future. Even if we are able to help you, questions along the lines of "why doesn't this work" or "why is my code broken" are a quite broad and won't be of much help to future viewers. I recommend skimming through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get a better idea of how Stack Overflow expects questions be formatted.

Answer (score 1):

`Random#nextInt(int)` will return a value from `0` to `bound - 1`, so it's possible that the `guess` could be `0` in your code.  You'd correct this by adding `1` to the guess, for example `int num = Machine.nextInt(10) + 1;`

Look at your logic...

```
else if(guess <= 0 && guess >= 11) {
```

if `guess <= 0` **AND** `guess >= 11` ... well, that's impossible.

I would change your logic flow, focusing on "happy paths" first.

That is, is the input within the acceptable range?  If so, is `guess == num` if so, you win, otherwise print error messages.

For example...

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
Random Machine = new Random();
int num = Machine.nextInt(10) + 1;

boolean done = false;
do {
    System.out.println("Guess the random generated number of the machine from 1-10");
    // Read the WHOLE line of text, removing the new line from the
    // buffer which would otherwise be left by Scanner#nextInt
    // and would cause no end of issues
    String text = input.nextLine();

    try {
        // Try and parse the text to an int
        int guess = Integer.parseInt(text);
        if (guess >= 1 && guess <= 10) {
            if (guess == num) {
                System.out.println("Correct number= " + num);
                System.out.println("You Win!");
                num = Machine.nextInt(10) + 1;
                System.out.println("Would you like to play another game? (Yes/No)");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Incorrect, guess again");
                System.out.println("Do you want to try again? (Yes/No)");
            }
            // Prompt the user to try again or play another game
            text = input.nextLine();
            done = !"yes".equals(text.toLowerCase());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Out of range");
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
        System.out.println("Not a valid number");
    }
} while (!done);
```

Comment: oh i see you even fix my random generated number. I'll study this carefully thank you very much